# Highlighting a Chunk of Code within a lstlisting

Tags: latex, listings, pdftex

I have a bunch of code in a lstlisting environment. How can I highlight (color background) just a particular chunk of code within the environment?

Comment: In the future, please ask LaTeX-related questions at: https://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis That would have been useful to know... 8 years ago.

Comment: There is a [package](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lstaddons/lstlinebgrd.pdf) called `lstlinebgrd` that does this, the only caveat is that it does not read the length of the texts automatically.

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593230/annotate-listing-with-overlays) uses overlays to highlight chunks of a listing.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use \colorbox and an escape character inside your listing:

Add to your preamble

```
  \usepackage{color}

  \definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.80}
```

then use it like this in your document:

```
  \begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=!]
  def mult(m: Matrix[Int], n: Matrix[Int]) {
    val p = !\colorbox{light-gray}{new MatrixInt}!(m.rows, n.cols)
  }
  \end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: I need something extra. I am using Beamer package for my presentation and I have to highlight code present in lstlisting. The difference in my need is I can't change the code inside lstlisting, like escaping or having special comment definition.

The code is present inside a different file which can't be changed. Copying the code and making modifications is not an option as there are many of them.

Can we indicate from outside (i.e. in \begin{lstlisting}) which lines to highlight?

Comment: Nice but it doesn't work with multiple lines and you are losing the syntax highlighting inside a `colorbox`.

Comment: When using LaTeX Beamer I had to mark the frame as fragile with `\begin{frame}[fragile]` to make it work.

Comment: Works great! Anyway, somehow I got the error `latex undefined color model` when changing colors to `\definecolor{light-green}{green}{0.80}`. That's why I switched to `\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.8,1.0,0.8}` instead. Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 13):

It's a bit cumbersome, but you can break the code into several `lstlisting` environments.

```tex
\begin{lstlisting}
line
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{pink}]
very
interesting
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{lstlisting}
line
line
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Will this work if you've got, for example, line numbers, or will they get restarted?

Comment: @Edd: By default, they will get restarted, but you can use the `firstnumber` keyword to fix that. In this example, you'd use `firstnumber=2` and `firstnumber=4` in the second and third `lstlisting` environments, respectively. Using `firstnumber=last` is supposed to continue the numbering from the previous `lstlisting` environment, but when I try it, it's off by one.

Comment: It turns out there's an even better solution to the numbering problem: use the `name` keyword (eg `\begin{lstlisting}[name=asdf, ...`). The name doesn't get displayed, and `lstlisting` environments with the same name share a line counter by default.

Comment: this works with multiple lines and the syntax highlighting get preserved. Anyone knows if this can be encapsulated in a `newcommand` or `newenvironment` ?

Comment: `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` didn't work for me to suppress separation between each block. Setting options `aboveskip=0` and `belowskip=0` as needed did.

Comment: lstlisting doesnot work with TexLive 2021

Answer (score 2):

There is a [package](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lstaddons/lstlinebgrd.pdf) called `lstlinebgrd` that does this

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}
\lstset{tabsize = 4, showstringspaces = false, breaklines = true, numbers = left, numberstyle = \tiny, basicstyle = \small \ttfamily, keywordstyle = \color{blue}, stringstyle = \color{red}, commentstyle = \color{green}, rulecolor = \color{black}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = python, frame = tRBl, basicstyle = \ttfamily \scriptsize, linebackgroundcolor = {\ifnum \value{lstnumber} = 8 \color{yellow} \fi, \ifnum \value{lstnumber} = 10 \color{yellow} \fi, \ifnum \value{lstnumber} = 12 \color{yellow} \fi}, linebackgroundsep = 2.2 em, linebackgroundwidth = 15 em]
import numpy
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model_input = Input(shape = x_train[0].shape)
x = Dense(120, activation = 'relu')(model_input)
x = Dropout(0.01)(x)
x = Dense(120, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.01)(x)
x = Dense(120, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.01)(x)
model_output = Dense(numpy.shape(y_train)[1])(x)
model = Model(model_input, model_output)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and you get

[image: highlight code]

it is however, still not optimized, you have to manually adjust the left and right edge of highlight bar, and setting multiple lines to highlight is cumbersome.

Comment: This looks nice, although `lstlinebgrd` is currently broken https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451532/recent-issues-with-lstlinebgrd-package-with-listings-after-the-latters-updates

Comment: @Supernormal Thanks for the information, hope it will recover soon!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for highlighting (parts of) individual lines using `tikz`:

```latex
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

% Command to place a TikZ anchor at the current position
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \coordinate (#1) at (0,0) {};}

\newcommand{\highlight}[2]{%
  \draw[yellow,line width=14pt,opacity=0.3]%
    ([yshift=4pt]#1) -- ([yshift=4pt]#2);%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@, language=C]
@\mytikzmark{hl1Start}@struct@\mytikzmark{hl1End}@ S {
    double @\mytikzmark{hl2Start}@salary_@\mytikzmark{hl2End}@;
};
    \end{lstlisting}
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \highlight{hl1Start}{hl1End}
        \highlight{hl2Start}{hl2End}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
        
\end{document}
```

and you get

[image]

so the `lstlisting`'s syntax highlighting is retained.

Answer (score 0):

the listings package provides backgroundcolor=\color{} as an option, but i'm sure that makes the whole BG color, not a chunk.

you could have a look at putting it a parbox with color, or the colorbox package.