# Manual syntax-highlighting in LaTeX-listings

Tags: latex, listings

I am using the `listings`-package to typeset some Haskell-sourcecode in my LaTeX-presentation. Is there a way to manually adjust the color of portions of the code? It's not regular syntax-highlighting what I am looking for, but a way to visually express and make it more easy to track how code-portions are shifted during term-rewriting. Therefore, i really want so say "beginning with this line let the code be green" and then "and now let the code be red", you got it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304315/highlighting-a-chunk-of-code-within-a-lstlisting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlighting a Chunk of Code within a lstlisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304315/highlighting-a-chunk-of-code-within-a-lstlisting)